# How to get total count using 3 tables with join in YII?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have 3 mysql tables (order , camp , user) as bellow values,

```
order_table
ID    camp_id       orderDate       
1       1           2015-01-01
2       1           2015-02-01
3       2           2015-03-01
4       3           2015-01-01
5       4           2015-04-01
6       2           2015-01-01
7       4           2015-07-01

camp_table
camp_id uid     camp name
1       10             first camp
2       11             second camp
3       12             third camp
4       10             forth camp

user_table
uid    uname
10      abc
11      xyz
12      wrt
```

like in above example i want to have count of order_table records for user_table (uid 10) in YII1 using

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
```

method.

or any other method but work fast as there is million of records in **order_table**

i have tried all options which i can find but none is working for me.

Thanks for help.

Comment: please describe which options you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
$criteria->condition = 'ot.orderDate =:Date';
$criteria->join = 'INNER JOIN camp_table ct ON ot.camp_id =ct.camp_id
INNER JOIN user_table ut on ut.uid  = ct.uid';
$criteria->params = array(':Date'=>$date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this may help you.
Yii Criteria:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
// $criteria->select    = '*';
$criteria->join      = 'INNER JOIN company ON order.company_id = company.id';
$criteria->join     .= 'INNER JOIN user ON company.user_id = user.id';
$criteria->condition = 'user.id=:id';
$criteria->params    = array(':id'=>10);

$customers = Order::model()->count($criteria);
```

Mysql Query:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `order`
INNER JOIN `company` ON `order`.`company_id` = `company`.`id`
INNER JOIN `user` ON `company`.`user_id` = `user`.`id`

WHERE `user`.`id` = 10;
```